# AngularJs custom replacement for ng-messages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created zz-messages directive in Angular 1.2.28 as a replacement of ng-messages to work in ie8.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.widgets')
        .directive('zzMessages', errorContainer);


    function errorContainer() {
        // Usage:
        //     <div zz-messages="field.$error">
        //          <span zz-message="required">This field is required</span>
        //     </div>
        //     Replacement for zz-message angular library to show single error on screen at a time and hide others

        return {
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
                var messageElements = element[0].querySelectorAll('[zz-message]');

                angular.forEach(messageElements, function (message) {
                    message.style.display = 'none';
                });

                $scope.$watchCollection(attrs.zzMessages, function (messages) {
                    var existingMessageOnView = false;
                    angular.forEach(messageElements, function (message) {
                        var zzMessage = angular.element(message).attr('zz-message');
                        if (!existingMessageOnView && messages[zzMessage] === true) {
                            message.style.display = 'block';
                            $(message).addClass('error-message');
                            existingMessageOnView = true;
                        } else {
                            message.style.display = 'none';
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }

 }());
```

It works fine for all the times except in a special case.

```
<div zz-forminput>
<label for="headquarter" class="col-md-4">Family Headquarter</label>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <input type="text" name="headquarter" id="headquarter" placeholder="K" data-ng-model="vm.userDetails.familyHQ" data-ng-maxlength="100" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/" maxlength="101">
    <div zz-messages="vm.basicDetailsForm.headquarter.$error" data-ng-if="vm.basicDetailsForm.headquarter.$dirty">
        <span zz-message="pattern">Family Headquarter can only contain alpha numeric characters</span>
        <span zz-message="maxlength">Family Headquarter cannot exceed 100 characters</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have my input field which is not required but it has a ng-maxlength="100" and ng-pattern. When the field is cleared, ng-invalid-maxlength and zz-invalid-pattern is added to input field.

Please fix this issue.

Comment: can you provide plunker/fiddle?

Comment: Here is the link to plunkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/zFz2uktotBm8omjaqm8q?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It got it solved. Problem was in a custom zzMinAlphaCharacters validator that I made. Thanks for support :)